# how to create a view in open atrium in drupal

Tags: drupal, open-atrium

i am new in drupal open atrium. i want to create a new feature in open atrium. so i go through the tutorial of how to create feature 
https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/449#an-imageboard-feature

but here i got a line like `Create a new view called imageboard using node as the base table`
i do not understand how to create new view using node.

here is the problem is that how to create a feature to add a view module in drupal atrium.

Answer (score 0):

you need to active the Views module.
Go to /admin/build/modules , scroll down an check the ckeckbox next to Views UI. Save your settings.
Now you should have a Views option in your admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

Same that in Drupal.
1-Install
2-Enable it
3-Structure - Views - Add new (or edit)
You can choose block, page or both