# To start with Drupal OA and create a custom feature

Tags: drupal, open-atrium

i am new in drupal open atrium. i do not have idea to create a new feature. so i go through the documentation of drupal open atrium. but after create a new imagecache preset on admin/build/imagecache. there is a line written that

```
Create a new view called imageboard using node as the base table.
```

i cant know how to create view node in open atrium . Is there any documentation for this or any reference site for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a view in open atrium in drupal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249816/how-to-create-a-view-in-open-atrium-in-drupal)

Answer (score 1):

Go to /admin/build/views/add.Add to view name, description, and tag and then click next. The node type is the default.